# Check the result of a method of an optional in one step not two

Tags: swift

Is there an easy way to do this in one if-statement, not two?

```
var timerSeconds: Timer?

func timerRelatedFunction(){
     if let valid: Bool = timerSeconds?.isValid {
          if(valid){
               ... do something with timerSeconds
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can compare the `Bool?` value to `true`:

```
var timerSeconds: Timer?

func timerRelatedFunction(){
     if timerSeconds?.isValid == true {
           ... do something with timerSeconds
     }
}
```

Since you want to do something with `timerSeconds`, you might want to unwrap it  and test with a single `if` like this:

```
if let timerSeconds = timerSeconds, timerSeconds.isValid {
    // now timerSeconds is the unwrapped value
}
```

Comment: The comparison to true effectively unwraps the optional result and checks the Bool in one statement.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
func timerRelatedFunction(){
     guard let valid = timerSeconds?.isValid else { return }
               ... do something with timerSeconds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```swift
func timerRelatedFunction(){
    guard let timerSeconds = timerSeconds, timerSeconds.isValid else { return }
    ... work with timerSeconds
}
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If your bool will result in `Optional<Bool> (i.e. Bool?)` you need to provide default value like this:

```
if timerSeconds?.isValid ?? false {
    //seconds timer is valid
}
```

But the above is not much clean and readable, so its better to compare with the specific value against which you want to perform some action **e.g.** You want to do some stuff if timeSeconds is valid then you can do something like this :

```
if timerSeconds?.isValid == true {
    //secondsTimer is valid
} else {
    //seconds timer is not valid
    //it means it may be false or nil
}
```

The above else statement is not suggesting that `timerSeconds?.isValid` is false. But it is can be both false or nil. So keep this into account while using this approach.